# Convert POST request for retrofit

Tags: android, web-services, rest, retrofit, android-webservice

I've the following POST request, that I'm testing with Advanced REST Client (Chrome Extension):

**URL**:
http://www.mysite.test/folder1/folder2/folder3/v1/register

**PARAMETERS:**

- *name:* myName
- *surname:* mySurname
- *email:* myEmail
- *password:* myPassword

The result is:

```
{
 error: false
 message: "You are successfully registered"
}
```

Now, all works with Advanced REST Client, but I want to translate this for Retrofit.

I created **RestClientUsers** :

```
public class RestClientUsers {
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.mysite.test/folder1/folder2/folder3";
private ApiServiceUsers apiServiceUsers;

public RestClientUsers() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("dd'-'MM'-'yyyy'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'")
            .create();
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build();

    apiServiceUsers = restAdapter.create(ApiServiceUsers.class);

}

public ApiServiceUsers getApiServiceUsers() {
    return apiServiceUsers;
}
}
```

But I don't know how to procede in order to obtain a perfectly working system.

I would like to execute the request, and store **error** and **message** into 2 variables.

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a few class like this.

```
public class ObjectPost {
String myName;
String mySurname;
String myEmail;
String myPassword;

public void setMyEmail(String myEmail) {
    this.myEmail = myEmail;
}

public void setMyName(String myName) {
    this.myName = myName;
}

public void setMyPassword(String myPassword) {
    this.myPassword = myPassword;
}

public void setMySurname(String mySurname) {
    this.mySurname = mySurname;
}}
```

///// *pojo receive*

```
public class ObjectRecieve {
Boolean error;
String message;

public Boolean isError() {
    return error;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}}
```

//

```
 public interface RestFul {
@POST("/v1/register")
void getValue(@Body ObjectPost mObject,Callback<ObjectRecieve> object);}
```

// Test within My MainActivity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("http://www.mysite.test/folder1/folder2/folder3")
        .build();

  RestFul  restFul  = restAdapter.create(RestFul.class);

  ObjectPost  objectPost = new ObjectPost();
  objectPost.setMyName("xxxx");
  objectPost.setMySurname("xxxx");
  objectPost.setMyPassword("xxxx");
  objectPost.setMyEmail("xxxx");



  restFul.getValue(objectPost,new Callback<ObjectRecieve>() {
   @Override
        public void success(ObjectRecieve result, Response response) {
          // receive your object here.
         Log.d("TAG",""+result.getMessage())


     })
   @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            System.out.println("error = [" + error + "]");                
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                    "Please check your internet connection.",       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();


        }


}
```

Comment: Hi, I've an error on restFul.getValue:
Class Anonymus Class derived from Callback must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method success(T, response) in 'Callback'

Comment: oh! , my wrong change this
**restFul.getValue(objectPost,new Callback<ObjectRecieve>()**

Comment: can you call  **restFul.getValue** Method? First time my code is  **restFul.getValue(objectPost,new Callback<Response >()**

Comment: Is this right?
restFul.getValue(objectPost, new Callback<RegistrationReceiver>() {
                    Override
                    public void success(RegistrationReceiver registrationReceiver, Response response) {
                        Log.d("OK", "");
                    }

                    Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        System.out.println("error = [" + error + "]");
                        
                    }
                });

Comment: Yes, after the request, failure method is fired:

ApiServiceUsers.getValue: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)

Comment: you try to add **@Body** in **void getValue( @Body ObjectPost mObject,Callback<ObjectRecieve> object);** . I forgot it.

Comment: I also tried with:

**@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")**

But this time **failure** is fired.

Comment: Check your parameters is correct ? try this >> *http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/*

Comment: you try to add **@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")**

Comment: I cant solve this ,but I found something, that seem to be useful [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945240/retrofit-bing-api-very-weird-bug-http-400-android) or [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127731/retrofit-post-return-bad-request-error-400)

Comment: I found something: the problem is that request is bad (error 400) because all of the parameters are missing, so using your code, I'm not passing the parameters..

Comment: I setted a higher log level, and the problem is that the parameters are passed in the json form in the request although I use **@Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded")**

Comment: Ok I found the solution, now it works:

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/v1/register")
 void getValue(@Field("myName")String myName,
                  @Field("mySurname")String mySurname,
                  @Field("myEmail")String myEmail,
                  @Field("myPassword")String myPassword,
                  Callback<RegistrationReceiver> object);